# Thevenin from terminals point of view in transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, thevenin

I know (from the textbook) the Thévenin expressions for the circuit from reference terminals `b-b'` are

$$V_{th} = V_{CC}\frac{R_2}{R_2+R_1}, R_{th} = R_1//R_2$$

But I'm not understanding how one gets there. How are the resistors parallel from the point of view of `b-b'`? The fact that \$R_1\$ is in a node that extends "behind" the reference terminals `b-b'` is really confusing.

And how come \$V_{th}\$ is a voltage divider if there's a current \$i_B\$ splitting into the `B` of the transistor and \$i_2\$ to GND? Also, how would a resistor at \$i_C\$ change the expression?

Is there another format to "see" this more obviously? I tried but couldn't simplify in a way that made sense to me from previous Thévenin problems.

[image]

Comment: Here you will find the answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/471906/calculation-of-base-current-and-what-decides-the-current-through-collector-emitt/471923#471923 Andy additional questions?

Comment: In addition, look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/337018/38098). :) And ludicrous? R1 and R2 are in parallel because your Vcc supply is 0 Ohms. A Vcc supply is both a direct short and also a voltage difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resistors are effectively in parallel because the voltage source Vcc is "stiff". If you try to change the voltage at b relative to b' then current through both resistors will change- the conductances add, the resistances are in parallel.

If the bias network looked like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRLxws.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then the Thevenin resistance would be R2 and the Thevenin voltage I1*R2.

---

With regard to your second question, when considering the Thevenin voltage, the current Ib is not there. You're **only** looking at three parts- the voltage source and the two resistors. Thevenin voltage is the open-circuit voltage.

Once you simplify the circuit to a single resistance R1||R2 and the Thevenin voltage source you can mentally reconnect it to the base.

Comment: I see! How about if I had a resistor at Ic, how would I handle it? Because now it is "linked" to the back of b-b'

Comment: Nothing connected parallel to the voltage source will change the voltage. If you add a resistor in series that is affected by Ic then it's a different kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is take the circuit Vcc, R1 and R2 as a separate from the rest of the circuit and find it's Thévenin equivalent, then you connect that with the rest of the circuit and figure out the rest. The base current \$i_B\$ is accounted for *after* you have the Thévenin equivalent of the bias divider.

When finding the Thévenin equivalent resistance you short voltage sources, so with Vcc shorted R1 and R2 are in parallel.